# Angular ejected project, is there still need for angular.cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[Angular ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject)

After I ejected a project, do I still need to have an **angular.cli** file in my project?
If yes, which are the keys on the **angular.cli** that are still useful?

Comment: yes angular.cli file is needed it contains all the essential details like styles,schema structure etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you still need the [@angular/cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) after using the eject feature? Obviously, you will not be using *all* of the features of the CLI afterward. You should not (I would not) remove it, if that is what you are asking. It still offers value after an eject.

Should you keep using it afterward? Yes, because you can still use the CLI after ejection to generate code from the command prompt. Ejecting a CLI project really only effects your ability to serve, build, and test an application.

I have an ejected project that I actively keep the CLI version up to date, and continue to use it to scaffold new code when needed. It is nice to keep it around. I have seen some questions/answers here that give the impression that you cannot use the CLI after an eject, but the fact is you can still use it for many things.